How much faster is recovery with SQL Accelerated Data Recovery (ADR)?
I've been doing ALOT of reading up on ADR. However, I cannot find any metrics or even anecdotal evidence to indicate the improvement in recovery time one could expect with ADR.
For example, recently we were required to recover a DB. Phase 1 and 2 completed in approx 4 hours. Phase 3 completed in approx 14 hours.
Recovery was necessary as the 150GB log file ran out of disk space due to a massive transaction.
This article states that ADR provides instantaneous transaction rollback. Does this mean that phase 3 would have been instant rather than 14hrs? Would phase 1 and 2 also be significantly faster?
Any guidance people could offer would be greatly appreciated.
